# Возврат массива из рекурсивной функции.

Tags: рекурсия, php

**Здравствуйте!** Вот у меня есть рекурсивная функция, сканирующая каталог и вложенные в него подкаталоги:

> ```
>  function scan($path,&$res, $type="*",
>  $type_sort="small", $lines=0) {  
>   $mass=scandir($path);
>   for($i=0;$i<=count($mass)-1;$i++)   {
>       if($mass[$i]!=".." &&
>  $mass[$i]!=".")          {  
>  if(strtolower($type_sort)=="small")
>       {
>           if($type=="*" || strstr(strtolower($mass[$i]),$type))
>           array_push($res,array($lines,$mass[$i]));
>       } else
>           if($type=="*" || strstr(strtolower($mass[$i]),$type)) 
>           array_push($res,array($lines,$path.$mass[$i]));
>       }       if(!strstr($mass[$i],".")) 
>       if(is_dir($path.'/'.$mass[$i]))
>  scan($path.'/'.$mass[$i],$res,$type,$type_sort,$lines+1);
>       }
>
>   }
> ```

Пытался возвратить этой функцией массив, содержащий все файлы подкаталогов и каталога,
не получилось! Пришлось передавать в качестве второго параметра массив-указатель на уже существующий(глобальный). Итог: функция ничего не возвращает. Взможно ли вообще получить значение из рекурсивной функции? **Спасибо.**

Comment: Удалите `>` из кода.

Comment: угу, удалил =)

Comment: Жуть-то какая... Попробовал сделать форматирование и разобраться в коде - не смог....

Comment: Ну ясное дело, я функцию не продокументировал же... 
1 параметр - путь к сканируемой директории
2 параметр - массив, в который будут помещаться имена файлов.
Остальные три параметра необязательные.

Comment: Не в комментариях дело... Могу сравнить ваш стиль - с почерком врача

Comment: Это не моя вина, стиль-то у меня не такой, как он отображен выше. Здесь же он, конечно, отобразился ужасно...

Answer (score 1):

Очень советую прежде чем вернуться к программированию, узнать побольше о форматировании кода и комментариях

```
function scan( $path, $ex = '*', $type_sort = 'small', $level = 0 ){
  $res = Array();
  $files = scandir( $path );
  $path_add = ( strtolower( $type_sort ) == 'small' ) ? $path : '';

  for ( $i = 0; $i < count( $files ); $i++ ){
    if ( $files[$i] != ".." && $files[$i] != "." ) {
      if ( $ex == "*" || strstr( strtolower( $files[$i] ), $ex ) ){
        $res[] = array( $level, $path_add . $files[$i] );
      }
    }

    if ( !strstr( $files[$i], "." ) && is_dir( $path.'/'.$files[$i] ) ){
      array_merge(
        scan( $path.'/'.$files[$i], $ex, $type_sort, $level + 1 );
      );
    }
  }

  return $res;
}
```

Comment: Вот, у меня именно такой стиль и был. Просто в ХешКоде не вместилась видимо полная строка, а я не заметил...